# RabbitMQ messaging middleware

Tags: java, rabbitmq

Can anybody please share an application that uses RabbitMQ. I need application codes that make use of RabbitMQ for sending messages. Please help.

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html

Comment: Thank you.I referred these..It contains only the rabbitmq simple message sending codes. But I would like to see how rabbitmq is used for an application.. eg- it can be a web application which is using rabbitmq for messaging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

[rabbitmq-perf-test](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-perf-test) is a Java command line program based on the RabbitMQ Java client. Its purpose is to put load on an AMQP broker.

For a larger, real world application, there is [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), written in Python, which allows you to run tasks asynchronously.